# android Place content below toolbar

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I have this layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_outline_white_24dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Setting `@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` attribute shifts the RecyclerView by the height of the Toolbar.

But what if I need the first element of the RecyclerView to be aligned to the status bar. 
I want the Toolbar to cover (be above) the first element.

In other words, I don't want any offset which `@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` behaviour entails.

Could you please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I just wrapped the AppbarLayout and the rest of my views (in your case the recyclerview) in a RelativeLayout and it works fine. I don't know if there are any downsides with that approach.

Comment: I tried wrapping, but then AppbarLayout refuses to scroll away

Comment: Aha, I didn't know you wanted that.

Answer (score 0):

The offset is not by `@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior behaviour` it's due to `AppBarLayout` it pushes the content down.

I'm not sure if there is any other better solution. But I'd suggest to remove the `AppBarLayout` to have your content go under the `Toolbar`. Moreover you might be need the scrolling behaviour for that you can check the library below.

It's been used by lots of apps like *Jair Music Player* even *WhatsApp* too uses it.

Library:
[Android Observable Scroll View](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView)

Comment: AppBarLayout and Google's Support Library are requirements. Anyway, thanks for the link, very nice library

Comment: @VitalyZinchenko thank you. If you really need to use Google's library then try wrapping the `AppBarLayout` with `FrameLayout`. Personally I use the combination of both the libraries you can see that in Jair Music Player if you want to.

Comment: AppBarLayout should be the direct child of CoordinatorLayout (from AppBarLayout source code) , so wrapping won't help

Comment: @VitalyZinchenko oh yeah I forgot that. Can you specify your use case in more detail? Maybe you can have a combo of both the libraries like I did